# Acceptance Tests of Draw2D

Tags: javascript, performance, selenium, acceptance-testing

I am currently cruising through acceptence tests of an web-based app with Selenium and have hit a wall in a section of our code that utilizes the Draw2D Javascript Library. Since the code here is a flavor of XML for SVG, I *can* write XPath selectors, but being already deep in the browser DOM and considering the performance hit in using XPath, these tests simply take too much time.

Has anyone heard of alternate methods for reaching into Draw2D?

Comment: While I'm not aware of any other solutions, I'd like to try to tinker with your selectors to see whether we can get something out of them. When not using IE, even the most complex XPath expressions are usually blazingly fast for me. If you're testing in IE, well, good luck to you :). I'd for example try to save one root element of the drawing and then search from it using `WebElement#findElement()`. The search context would be simplified a lot this way.